# How does the ipv4 option "record route" work?

Tags: network, internet, programming

As written in the [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-20) this option is useful to record the addresses of the routers that an ip datagram goes through.

I'm sending an ip datagram with an [ICMP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792#page-14) echo message, i've set the option type (of the header ip) on 7, the option length on 7 and the pointer on 4.

I expect an echo reply with the first router address to come back, but this doesn't happends. Am i doing something wrong or the option is not supported anymore?(If i don't set the options, the echo response comes back as expect)

Comment: You might have more luck with question over on the network engineering stack exchange: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll try, ty so much @iain

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for this option to be blocked by ISPs.  Since you are getting no route information at all, the router closest to you (i.e. your home or office router) is probably black-holing those packets.  If you can reconfigure that device, you may well find that you can get little or no more information from downstream for the same reason.